# How to print the output in desired way?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like the print the output of nested dictionaries as desired way, but not getting any ideas to do the same. Could any one help regarding this case.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#Using python 2.7

li= [ {1: {"count_1": 12, "count_3": 899, "count_2": 100}},
      {2: {"count_1": 13, "count_3": 100, "count_2": 200}},
      {3: {"count_1": 14, "count_3": 999, "count_2": 300}},
      {4: {"count_1": 15, "count_3": 99, "count_2": 400}}]

fmt = "{:} {:}  {:}  {:}   {:}  "
print fmt.format("name", "stat1", "stat2", "stat3", "stat4")

for dict_data in li:
  for parent_key,value in dict_data.iteritems():
     for k,v in value.iteritems():
         print k, "->", v
```

**Getting Output as:**

```
name, stat1  stat2  stat3   stat4  
count_3 -> 899
count_2 -> 100
count_1 -> 12
count_3 -> 100
count_2 -> 200
count_1 -> 13
count_3 -> 999
count_2 -> 300
count_1 -> 14
count_3 -> 99
count_2 -> 400
count_1 -> 15
```

Expected output:

```
    name       stat1  stat2  stat3   stat4  
    count_3     899     100   999      99
    count_2     100     200   300      400
    count_1     12      13    14       15
```

Using : Python 2.7, I want to avoid `pandas`

Comment: Have you taken a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)

Comment: I don't want to use pandas..

Comment: Okay @scott. Format using tabs.

Comment: careful you'll have to use `sorted(dict_data.iteritems())` because order of dictionary keys isn't guaranteed in python 2.x

Comment: You are Correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach. You can extract "row names" and sort them first as each goes on a separate line, and then extract values for each row from `li`:

```
fmt = "{:}\t{:}\t{:}\t{:}\t{:}  "
print(fmt.format("name", "stat1", "stat2", "stat3", "stat4"))

rows = sorted(li[0][1].keys(), reverse=True) # ['count_3', 'count_2', 'count_1']
for rname in rows:
    stats = [val[rname] for d in li for val in d.values()]
    print(fmt.format(rname, *stats))
```

**Output**

```
name    stat1   stat2   stat3   stat4                                                                                                                                              
count_3 899     100     999     99                                                                                                                                                 
count_2 100     200     300     400                                                                                                                                                
count_1 12      13      14      15
```